# Github API total count and results mismatch

Tags: python, github, github-api

I was wondering if someone could help to figure out the following problem:

I am fetching some user data Github API v3 and I noticed the value "total_count" does not match the sum of the number of records per page, example:

GET on https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3AGermany returns the users with location set to "Germany", with 30 results per page.

```
{
  "total_count": 102814,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [ user1, user2, user3, ...]
```

Headers state that there are 34 pages (see "last")

```
<https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3AGermany&page=2>; rel="next", <https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3AGermany&page=34>; rel="last"
```

So 30 entries per page, 34 pages that makes 30 * 34 = 1'020 total; but that is 100 times less than expected. Or in other words, only 1% of the total_count. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the [GitHub Developer Search API documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/search/) says,

> The Search API helps you search for the specific item you want to find. For example, you can find a user or a specific file in a repository. Think of it the way you think of performing a search on Google. It's designed to help you find the one result you're looking for (or maybe the few results you're looking for). Just like searching on Google, you sometimes want to see a few pages of search results so that you can find the item that best meets your needs. To satisfy that need, the GitHub Search API provides **up to 1,000 results for each search**.

And suggests that you can narrow your search using queries.

Comment: Thanks @ababak, I only read the docs for v3/ endpoint and assumed /search wouldn't be any different 
https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting